# Reading MEDIUMBLOB from MySQL in java

Tags: java, mysql, blob

This is for the first time I am working with the Blob data types. 
I am storing the image files in MEDIUMBLOB datatype in MySQL database. Now, I want to retrieve it using a JAVA application. 
So far, I found tutorials making use of `com.mysql.jdbc.Blob`.
 I tried,

```
Blob imgAsBlob = resultset.getBlob("image");
byte[] imgAsBytes = imgAsBlob.getBytes(1, (int) imgAsBlob.length());
```

but I get an error at `imgAsBlob.getBytes(1, (int) imgAsBlob.length())` because the second argument is larger (46352) than the BLOB's length:

```
java.sql.SQLException: "pos" + "length" arguments cannot be larger than the BLOB's length.
```

Is there any other way than getBlob() method or any other class than `com.mysql.jdbc.Blob` which I can use?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you pass the value `1` as the first parameter? That cuts off the first byte. Use `imgAsBlob.getBytes(1, (int) imgAsBlob.length())`

Comment: @f1sh I didn't get your point. The code is the same as the one you suggested to use. Besides Position 'pos' cannot be < 1.

Comment: You are correct, the `1` is supposed to be a `0`. I wasn't aware that you cannot pass 0 as an argument. What's the value of `imgAsBlob.length()`?

Comment: `imgAsBlob.length() is 46352`

Comment: that should not be happening. [The source code](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/mysql/jdbc/Blob.java.html) shows that `pos` is decreased by one and the check should not fail. I have no idea what leads to this. Can you debug into the `getBytes` method?